# How to customize the MathematicaClosingDialog.nb?

Tags: front-end, gui-construction, customization, windows

With *Mathematica* 10 came the closing dialog notebook, which probably most of you deactivated. (You can bring it back by dechecking "Always exit after closing last window" in Edit->Preferences->Interface.) I just kept it, because my *Mathematica* installation gets non-responsive (often accompanied by the pop up of the "Progress" window) in several situations including start up.

However, the default closing dialog 
[image: defaultClosingDialog]
isn't very functional.

Therefore I'd like to customize it to get, e.g. something like:
[image: customClosingDialog_Explained]
Where the "Quit" button is replaced by a "Quit Kernel" button that just quits the kernel, as there is no advantage to use the default "Quit" instead of the close window X. Furthermore I'd like to extend the closing dialog by adding additional buttons, e.g. a "Evaluate Specified Notebook" button that will evaluate a notebook file, whose path is defined in some .txt file.

The only way to read the default *MathematicaClosingDialog.nb* into Mma I found is

```
nb = Import[FileNameJoin[{$InstallationDirectory, "SystemFiles", "FrontEnd", 
            "TextResources", "MathematicaClosingDialog.nb"}]]
```

The output of this import looks like a mess, though.

In summary:

1. How to replace the "Quit" button with a "Quit Kernel" button?
2. How to add additional buttons, like a "Evaluate Specified Notebook" button?
3. Can the directory for the *MathematicaClosingDialog.nb* be changed?
   (I couldn't find it in the "Option Inspector".)

Comment: I'm not seeing a closing dialog in V10 on OS X.

Comment: @m_goldberg I don't know if there is one on OS X, but is "Always exit after closing last window" unchecked in Edit->Preferences->Interface? Or is this item nonexisting on OS X?

Comment: I don't see the preference item you mention.

Comment: @m_goldberg I do not think this dialog exists under OS X, because it depends on the fact that under Windows MMA 10 has a menu bar in each notebook window. So if you close the last nb, you are given the choice -in Preferences- to either quit MMA for good or open the ClosingDialog (with another menu bar). Under OS X I understand that MMA 10 still has a global menu bar, so this issue does not arise.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It turned out that the *MathematicaClosingDialog.nb* is a nice example for a graphical user interface that solely uses the FrontEnd MathKernel. On the downside, one has to deal with low-level code.

First I made a copy of the original *MathematicaClosingDialog.nb*, renamed it as *MathematicaClosingDialog_Default.nb*, and then imported it into a notebook:

```
nb = Import[
      FileNameJoin[{$InstallationDirectory, "SystemFiles", "FrontEnd", 
      "TextResources", "MathematicaClosingDialog_Default.nb"}]];
```

The result of this `Import` is a `Notebook` expression, with a bunch of low-level code. However, it isn't too hard to figure out what the components mean, if one doesn't get intimidated and discouraged by this code, that initially looks like a mess.

## "Quit Kernel" Button

The definition of the "Quit" button can be found at

```
nb[[1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3]]
```

and converted into the familiar appearance by

```
ToExpression@nb[[1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3]]
```

> [image: QuitButton]

It can be utilized to create the new "Quit Kernel" button by

```
newQuit = nb[[1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3]] /.    
   {FEPrivate`FrontEndResourceString["quitButtonText"] -> "Quit Kernel", 
    EventHandlerTag[{"MouseClicked" :> DialogReturn[FrontEndTokenExecute["FrontEndQuit"]], 
      PassEventsDown -> Automatic, PassEventsUp -> True}] -> 
     EventHandlerTag[{"MouseClicked" :> FrontEndTokenExecute["EvaluatorQuit", "Local"], 
       PassEventsDown -> Automatic, PassEventsUp -> True}]};
```

and then visualized with

```
ToExpression@newQuit
```

> [image: QuitKernelButton]

Clicking on this button will quit the kernel "Local". (More precisely it will bring up the "Do you really want to quit the kernel?" dialog.) It is important to explicitly include a kernel name in `FrontEndTokenExecute["EvaluatorQuit", "Local"]`, as the closing dialog will run with the FrontEnd MathKernel and not with the "Local" kernel or whatever kernel you used as "Notebook's Kernel".

## "Evaluate Specified Notebook" Button

For the second task a suitable icon is needed. I created one based on the notebook icon:

```
nbIcon = Import[
  FileNameJoin[{$InstallationDirectory, "SystemFiles", "FrontEnd", 
  "SystemResources", "Bitmaps", "Product", "Document@144dpi.png"}]]
nbIcon = ImageResize[ImageCrop[nbIcon, 55], 39]
Export[FileNameJoin[{NotebookDirectory[], "Document.png"}], nbIcon]
```

> [image: Document]

and a hover icon:

```
dcs = DominantColors[nbIcon]
nbIconHover = ColorReplace[nbIcon, (First@dcs) -> ColorData["HTML"]["DodgerBlue"]]
Export[FileNameJoin[{NotebookDirectory[], "Document-Hover.png"}], nbIconHover]
```

> [image: DocumentHover]

I then copied these icons into the *$InstallationDirectory\SystemFiles\FrontEnd\SystemResources\Bitmaps\Dialog\Closing* directory.

The new button will be based on the "New Notebook" button:

```
evalSNB = nb[[1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]] /. 
  {FrontEnd`ToFileName[{"Dialogs", "Closing"}, "File.png"] ->
    FrontEnd`ToFileName[{"Dialogs", "Closing"}, "Document.png"],
   FrontEnd`ToFileName[{"Dialogs", "Closing"}, "File-Hover.png"] -> 
    FrontEnd`ToFileName[{"Dialogs", "Closing"}, "Document-Hover.png"], 
   FEPrivate`FrontEndResource["MathematicaClosingDialog", "NewNotebook"] -> 
    "Evaluate Specified NB", 
   RGBColor[0.9294117647058824, 0.1803921568627451, 0.01568627450980392] -> 
    RGBColor[0.08104575163398693, 0.3058823529411765, 0.6640522875816994],
   EventHandlerTag[{"MouseClicked" :> DialogReturn[FrontEndTokenExecute["New"]], 
     PassEventsDown -> Automatic, PassEventsUp -> True}] -> 
    EventHandlerTag[{"MouseClicked" :> FrontEndTokenExecute[NotebookOpen["D:\\selectedNB.nb", Visible -> False],"EvaluateNotebook", "Local"], 
      PassEventsDown -> Automatic, PassEventsUp -> True}]};
```

Since one can't import a txt file using the FrontEnd (at least not with `Import`), a notebook file *selectedNB.nb* with the following content is used as an intermediate:

```
FrontEndTokenExecute[NotebookOpen[Import["D:\\specifiedNB.txt"], Visible -> False], 
  "EvaluateNotebook", "Local"]
NotebookClose[]
```

With the option `Visible -> False` the notebook won't be displayed. If you prefer to see the notebook while it is evaluated, just remove this option.
The txt file contains the directory of the notebook with the interesting code. That notebook ends with `SystemOpen` functions to display the calculated graphs and finally a `NotebookClose[]`.

## Custom Closing Dialog

Now our custom closing dialog is created with:

```
newClosingDialog = nb;
newClosingDialog[[1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3]] = newQuit;
newClosingDialog[[1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]] = 
  Append[newClosingDialog[[1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]], {evalSNB, "", ""}];
newClosingDialog[[1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1]] = 
  Append[RowSpacings -> 5]@newClosingDialog[[1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1]];
```

Where the last command increased the spacing between the first and the new second row.
You can use

```
newClosingDialog[[1, 3]] // CellPrint
```

to visualize the main part of the new dialog.

Finally it is exported with:

```
Export[FileNameJoin[{NotebookDirectory[], "MathematicaClosingDialog.nb"}], newClosingDialog]
```

Unfortunately, I couldn't find a file specification for the closing dialog in the "Option Inspector" and therefore had to copy my custom *MathematicaClosingDialog.nb* into the folder of the default closing dialog. (!! This will override the original *MathematicaClosingDialog.nb* !!)

---

[image: CustomClosingDialog]

Comment: What a professional answer. +1